# Is there something like C#'s debug display attributes for debugging Rust in VS Code?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rust

It is hard and time-consuming to navigate all the nested object arms of your variable object when debugging Rust code in VS Code.

Is it possible to use a more human readable representation of the content of the variable, such as what is shown when hovering the cursor over the variable in an IDE during debugging?

For instance, viewing the content `"b"` of the String variable `ident` gets displayed in Visual Studio Code like:

[image: Viewing a string in VS Code]

It would be nice if there was the possibility see a more concise thumbnail of the content as [debugger display attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/enhancing-debugging-with-the-debugger-display-attributes) in C# does.

I don't like `println!` debugging :p

Is there a difference between using GDB or LLDB as the debugging engine?

As another example, a variable of type `Symbol`

```rust
pub struct Symbol {
    pub ident: String,
    pub childs: Vec<Symbol>,
    pub depth: u32,
    pub fixed: bool,
}
```

Is displayed in the VS Code debugger like:

[image: Display complex type]

`fmt::Debug` is implemented  for that struct to return `A(a)` and not `{depth:2, fixed:true}` as shown in the picture.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. There is the `#[derive(Debug)]` attribute which you can annotate your struct with and there is the `dbg!` macro which can be uses as an alternative to `println` debugging.
Please clarify your question what is wrong, else this is sadly offtopic :/

Comment: Either using the `println!` or the `dbg!` macro: I do not want to modify the code for instrospection during debugging.

Comment: I guess it was shown for the Rust code too in the VS Code if you import LLDB or GDB plugin.

Comment: @AkinerAlkan What vscode extension do you mean? I am using the debug type `cppdbg` with MiMode `gdb` in vs code.

Comment: I use the LLDB debugger extension in vs code, and it works well AFAIK

Comment: There is `rust-gdb` or `rust-lldb`. Have you tried those?

Comment: @hellow How do I setup lldb formatter in vscode?

Comment: @hellow do you mean `rust-lldb`as debug type in vs code?

Comment: Yes. I never used vs code nor I have knowledge on how to use or configure it. You have to help here ;) I can only give you some bread crumbs. Try it out please!

Comment: Using `lldb` as debugger type is much better than gdb.

Comment: gdb has python pretty-printers which can be registered and will control how a given type is displayed; this may not match C#'s level... mostly because gdb does not have the degree of integration that the C# debugger has.

Answer (score 0):

- In a Microsoft world, MSVC supports [natvis](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/natvis) - a fairly evolved CPP standard that Rust source code already uses -- see [src/etc/natvis](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/src/etc/natvis). AFAIK, natvis files are linked into .pdb files, so they might not work with non-pdb platforms yet (unconfirmed).
- There is a pre-RFC [discussion](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-natvis-support-for-rust/15477/9) in the Rust community on how to handle natvis going forward.
- JetBrain's CLion has some [natvis support](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2021/06/clion-2021-2-eap-natvis-support-freertos/#improved_natvis_support) (blog) when used with LLDB debugger, not sure if it will work for Rust too.
- Personally, I would love for this to go beyond Microsoft-only toolchain, and to also visualize complex types - the way [DebuggerTypeProxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-debuggertypeproxy-attribute?view=vs-2022) works for complex C# objects. `natvis` seems like a step in that direction.